Fitting two curves with a variable number of parameters using `scipy.optimize.least_squares()`
I'm writing code to fit parameters of related pairs of functions from a family using the scipy.optimize.least_squares() function and it seems that the test parameters are not being passed to the function correctly. Here's a simplified illustration of the problem.
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import scipy.optimize
import math

Ha = {'H': lambda x, a, b : a + b*x, 'nParams': 2}
Hb = {'H': lambda x, a, b, c : a + b*x + c*x*x, 'nParams': 3}
Hc = {'H': lambda x, a, b, c, d : a*math.cos(b*(x-c)) + d, 'nParams': 4}

points1 = [(1,0), (2,4), (3,5), (7,8)]
points2 = [(1,1), (2,6), (4,1), (6,6)]

def coupled_1 (x, g, *params, **kwargs):
    H1, H2 = kwargs.values() # H1 and H2 are dictionaries containing the two curves
                             # to be fit, 'H', and their respective numbers of
                             # parameters, 'nParams'
    matrix = np.diag([H1['H'](x, *params[:H1['nParams']]), H2['H'](x, *params[H1['nParams']:])]) \
            + np.diag([g],k=1) + np.diag([g],k=-1)
    return la.eigh(matrix)['eigenvalues'][0]

def coupled_2 (x, g, *params, **kwargs):
    H1, H2 = kwargs.values()
    matrix = np.diag([H1['H'](x, *params[:H1['nParams']]), H2['H'](x, *params[H1['nParams']:])]) \
            + np.diag([g],k=1) + np.diag([g],k=-1)
    return la.eigh(matrix)['eigenvalues'][1]

def getParameters(H1, H2, pts1, pts2):
    nParams = H1['nParams'] + H2['nParams']
    # These points sometimes come in pairs and sometimes don't so I've found no better way to zip them
    pts     = [(p1, p2) for p1 in pts1 for p2 in pts2 if p1[0] == p2[0]]
    res     = lambda *params, **kwargs: \
                     np.sqrt(sum( [( p[0][1]-coupled_1(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 \
                     + (p[1][1]-coupled_2(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 for p in pts] ))
    result  = scipy.optimize.least_squares(res,[1] + [0]*nParams, kwargs={'H1':H1,'H2':H2})
    return result['x']

params = getParameters(Ha, Hc, points1, points2)

I'm receiving the following error from Ha()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 37
     34     result  = scipy.optimize.least_squares(res,[1] + [0]*nParams, kwargs={'H1':H1,'H2':H2})
     35     return result['x']
---> 37 params = getParameters(Ha, Hc, points1, points2)
     38 print(params)

Cell In[5], line 34, in getParameters(H1, H2, pts1, pts2)
     30 pts     = [(p1, p2) for p1 in pts1 for p2 in pts2 if p1[0] == p2[0]]
     31 res     = lambda *params, **kwargs: \
     32                  np.sqrt(sum( [( p[0][1]-coupled_1(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 \
     33                  + (p[1][1]-coupled_2(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 for p in pts] ))
---> 34 result  = scipy.optimize.least_squares(res,[1] + [0]*nParams, kwargs={'H1':H1,'H2':H2})
     35 return result['x']

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py:830, in least_squares(fun, x0, jac, bounds, method, ftol, xtol, gtol, x_scale, loss, f_scale, diff_step, tr_solver, tr_options, jac_sparsity, max_nfev, verbose, args, kwargs)
    827 if method == 'trf':
    828     x0 = make_strictly_feasible(x0, lb, ub)
--> 830 f0 = fun_wrapped(x0)
    832 if f0.ndim != 1:
    833     raise ValueError("`fun` must return at most 1-d array_like. "
    834                      "f0.shape: {0}".format(f0.shape))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py:825, in least_squares.<locals>.fun_wrapped(x)
    824 def fun_wrapped(x):
--> 825     return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))

Cell In[5], line 32, in getParameters.<locals>.<lambda>(*params, **kwargs)
     29 # These points sometimes come in pairs and sometimes don't so I've found no better way to zip them
     30 pts     = [(p1, p2) for p1 in pts1 for p2 in pts2 if p1[0] == p2[0]]
     31 res     = lambda *params, **kwargs: \
---> 32                  np.sqrt(sum( [( p[0][1]-coupled_1(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 \
     33                  + (p[1][1]-coupled_2(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 for p in pts] ))
     34 result  = scipy.optimize.least_squares(res,[1] + [0]*nParams, kwargs={'H1':H1,'H2':H2})
     35 return result['x']

Cell In[5], line 32, in <listcomp>(.0)
     29 # These points sometimes come in pairs and sometimes don't so I've found no better way to zip them
     30 pts     = [(p1, p2) for p1 in pts1 for p2 in pts2 if p1[0] == p2[0]]
     31 res     = lambda *params, **kwargs: \
---> 32                  np.sqrt(sum( [( p[0][1]-coupled_1(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 \
     33                  + (p[1][1]-coupled_2(p[0][0], *params, **kwargs) )**2 for p in pts] ))
     34 result  = scipy.optimize.least_squares(res,[1] + [0]*nParams, kwargs={'H1':H1,'H2':H2})
     35 return result['x']

Cell In[5], line 17, in coupled_1(x, g, *params, **kwargs)
     14 H1, H2 = kwargs.values() # H1 and H2 are dictionaries containing the two curves
     15                          # to be fit, 'H', and their respective numbers of
     16                          # parameters, 'nParams'
---> 17 matrix = np.diag([H1['H'](x, *params[:H1['nParams']]), H2['H'](x, *params[H1['nParams']:])]) \
     18         + np.diag([g],k=1) + np.diag([g],k=-1)
     19 return la.eigh(matrix)['eigenvalues'][0]

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'

It seems that the *params list is not making it to Ha(), but I'm unsure why.

Here is a different approach for the res function, this works for me.
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import scipy.optimize
import math

# Define the dictionaries for the functions
Ha = {'H': lambda x, a, b: a + b*x, 'nParams': 2}
Hb = {'H': lambda x, a, b, c: a + b*x + c*x*x, 'nParams': 3}
Hc = {'H': lambda x, a, b, c, d: a*math.cos(b*(x-c)) + d, 'nParams': 4}

points1 = [(1,0), (2,4), (3,5), (7,8)]
points2 = [(1,1), (2,6), (4,1), (6,6)]

def coupled_1(x, g, *params, **kwargs):
    H1, H2 = kwargs['H1'], kwargs['H2']
    matrix = np.diag([H1['H'](x, *params[:H1['nParams']]), H2['H'](x, *params[H1['nParams']:])]) \
            + np.diag([g], k=1) + np.diag([g], k=-1)
    return la.eigh(matrix)[0][0]  # Get the smallest eigenvalue

def coupled_2(x, g, *params, **kwargs):
    H1, H2 = kwargs['H1'], kwargs['H2']
    matrix = np.diag([H1['H'](x, *params[:H1['nParams']]), H2['H'](x, *params[H1['nParams']:])]) \
            + np.diag([g], k=1) + np.diag([g], k=-1)
    return la.eigh(matrix)[0][1]  # Get the second smallest eigenvalue

def getParameters(H1, H2, pts1, pts2):
    nParams = H1['nParams'] + H2['nParams']
    # Filter points with matching x-values
    pts = [(p1, p2) for p1 in pts1 for p2 in pts2 if p1[0] == p2[0]]
    
    def res(params, **kwargs):
        error_sum = 0
        for p1, p2 in pts:
            x_val = p1[0]
            y1 = p1[1]
            y2 = p2[1]
            error_sum += (y1 - coupled_1(x_val, *params, **kwargs))**2
            error_sum += (y2 - coupled_2(x_val, *params, **kwargs))**2
        return np.sqrt(error_sum)
    
    # Initial guess for parameters
    initial_guess = [1] + [0]*nParams
    
    # Optimize parameters using least squares method
    result = scipy.optimize.least_squares(res, initial_guess, kwargs={'H1': H1, 'H2': H2})
    
    return result['x']

# Obtain parameters
params = getParameters(Ha, Hc, points1, points2)
print(params)


I see now where my issue was least_squares() passes the list of guess parameters, x0 as a list, not as separate parameters, to the residual function, so I just needed to pass x0 as a list, rather than unpacking it.

The theme is: Python offers OK tools and bad tools, and you've used the bad ones (poorly-typed dictionaries, lambdas, positional arguments, args/kwargs abuse, untyped signatures).
import inspect
from typing import NamedTuple, Protocol

import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize


def h_a(x: float, a: float, b: float) -> float:
    return a + b*x


def h_c(x: float, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float) -> float:
    return a * np.cos(b*(x - c)) + d


class Hsignature(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: float, *args: float) -> float: ...


class Hfun(NamedTuple):
    call: Hsignature
    n_params: int

    @classmethod
    def from_method(cls, call: Hsignature) -> 'Hfun':
        sig = inspect.signature(call)
        return cls(
            call=call, n_params=len(sig.parameters) - 1,
        )


def coupled(
    x: float, g: float,
    H1: Hfun, h1_params: np.ndarray,
    H2: Hfun, h2_params: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    matrix = np.array((
        (H1.call(x, *h1_params), g),
        (g, H2.call(x, *h2_params)),
    ))

    return np.linalg.eigh(matrix).eigenvalues


def res(
    params: np.ndarray,
    pts: list[tuple[
        tuple[float, float],
        tuple[float, float],
    ]],
    H1: Hfun,
    H2: Hfun,
) -> np.ndarray:
    (g,), h1_params, h2_params = np.split(
        params,
        (1, 1 + H1.n_params),
    )

    return np.sqrt(
        # This needs to be vectorised via np.linalg.norm
        sum(
            (
                p[0][1] - coupled(
                    x=p[0][0], g=g,
                    H1=H1, h1_params=h1_params,
                    H2=H2, h2_params=h2_params,
                )[0]
            )**2 +
            (
                p[1][1] - coupled(
                    x=p[1][0], g=g,
                    H1=H1, h1_params=h1_params,
                    H2=H2, h2_params=h2_params,
                )[1]
            )**2
            for p in pts
        )
    )


def get_parameters(
    H1: Hfun,
    H2: Hfun,
    pts1: np.ndarray,
    pts2: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    n_params = H1.n_params + H2.n_params
    # These points sometimes come in pairs and sometimes don't so I've found no better way to zip them
    pts = [
        (p1, p2)
        for p1 in pts1
        for p2 in pts2
        if p1[0] == p2[0]
    ]

    x0 = np.zeros(1 + n_params)
    x0[0] = 1
    result = scipy.optimize.least_squares(
        fun=res, x0=x0,
        kwargs={'pts': pts, 'H1': H1, 'H2': H2},
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    return result.x


def main() -> None:
    points1 = np.array(((1, 0), (2, 4), (3, 5), (7, 8)))
    points2 = np.array(((1, 1), (2, 6), (4, 1), (6, 6)))
    Ha = Hfun.from_method(h_a)
    Hc = Hfun.from_method(h_c)

    params = get_parameters(H1=Ha, H2=Hc, pts1=points1, pts2=points2)
    print(params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

[-3.53915670e-09 -5.99847551e+00  5.99900390e+00  1.24999998e+00
  2.73044168e-08  0.00000000e+00  1.24999999e+00]


Possible optimization - eigvalsh can be used if you don't care about the eigenvectors. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvalsh.html
